# Numerical estimates on asymptotic of given functional as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Consider the following functional :

$$
I(x,s) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy, s) − F(x −\mathrm iy, s)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$
where $ F(z, s) = \dfrac{\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)]}{z^s} $.

Let us restrict $s\in[0,1]$

In Mathematica

```
f[z_, s_] = Sin[π Gamma[z]/(2z)]^2/z^s; 
II[x_, s_] := Integrate[(f[x + I y, s] - f[x - I y, s])/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1), 
             {y, 0,Infinity}]
```

> > Can we get sharp numerical asymptotic of $I(x)$ as as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

> > Also, can we get quantitative upper and lower bound estimations on the functional ?

Update : Also try for $$F(z)= \log(z){\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)]}$$

Comment: Have you tried `Series[]`?

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you for comment,  sir . I've not used it. Actually this is my first day and second question on this site . I'm not used to Mathematica .

Comment: I’m away from my computer, I can’t try it. It may or may not work on `Integrate[]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 doesn't seem to work trivially at least. The function f is rather pathological near the origin. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vjT6m.png)

Comment: The most important cases for my purpose is $s=1$ or very near to 1 and $s=0$ or very near to zero

Comment: @Michael E2 , chris : Any updates on the question?

Comment: Maybe a little help to Mathematica using the Abel-Plana formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula , could come in handy.

Comment: For my system the correct input of `f[z,s]` shoud be: `f[z_, s_] := (Sin[Pi Gamma[z]/(2 z)]^2)/z^s;`

Comment: Seems that the real part of the integrand function is 0 for $s∈[0,1]$.