# Accurate numerical values of a given functional

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the following functional :

$$
I(x,s) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy, s) − F(x −\mathrm iy, s)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$
where $ F(z, s) = \dfrac{\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)]}{z^s} $.

Consider z to be greater than 1

In Mathematica

```
f[z_, s_] = Sin[π*Gamma[z]/2z]^2/z^s; 
II[x_, s_] := Integrate[(f[x + I y, s] - f[x - I y, s])/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1), 
             {y, 0,Infinity}]
```

I want to calculate the values of function for x at least upto 20 and s=2.

I think Mathematica fail to calculate after x=5. (Why?)

Comment: Related/duplicates: [(215320)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215320), [(216277)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216277)

Comment: "...for x at least upto 20 and z=2" makes no sense since `z = x + I y` in your code. -- Did you mean `πGamma` or `π * Gamma`? -- Have you seen `NIntegrate`?

Comment: @MichaelE2  thank you for the comments. The duplicates you mentioned are not duplicates there are slight changes in each of them. Also I made a typo while writing z instead of s.

Comment: In Mathematica, `πGamma` is a single `Symbol`. Is `πGamma[z]`  supposed to be the number `Pi` times the gamma function, or a function called `πGamma[z]`? I have not heard of  a function called `πGamma[z]`, so what is its definition?

Comment: @MichaelE2 again sorry I have π*Gamma in mind. If you could provide me with the comparitive plots wrt parameters 2,3,4 etc for x upto atleast 20 it would be very appreciated

Comment: Your integrand for `x == 5` can be up to 10^150 in magnitude; for `x == 6`, up to 10^900; for `x >= 17.4`, it will exceed `$MaxNumber`, about `10^(10^15)`. Numbers larger than `$MaxNumber` cannot be represented in *Mathematica*, so integrals with `x` greater than `17` or so will be impossible. An oscillatory integral will need a `WorkingPrecision` large enough that the oscillations do not a catastrophic loss of precision due to cancellation of positive and negative terms. It might make integrals with `x > 5` or so intractable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numerical estimates on asymptotic of given functional as $x\rightarrow \infty$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215320/numerical-estimates-on-asymptotic-of-given-functional-as-x-rightarrow-infty)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code:  (made mistake with formula)**
But it still oscillates wildly.

```
f1[x_, y_, s_] := Sin[(Pi Gamma[x + I y])/(2 (x + I y))]^2/(x + I y)^s;
f2[x_, y_, s_] := Sin[(Pi Gamma[x - I y])/(2 (x - I y))]^2/(x - I y)^s;
Manipulate[
 Plot[Im@(1/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1) (f1[x, y, s] - f2[x, y, s])) /. {x -> 
     myX, s -> 2}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], {{myX, 5}, 2, 8}]
```

Integrating with x=8 causes a problem with convergence:

```
NIntegrate[(1/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1) (f1[x, y, s] - f2[x, y, s])) /. {x -> 
    8, s -> 2}, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

Use Manipulate to investigate function as x is varied:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Im@(1/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1) (f1[x, y, s] - f2[x, y, s])) /. {x -> 
     myX, s -> 2}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], {{myX, 5}, 2, 8}]
```

The plot below is for x=6.6.

[image]

Comment: sir I think  you made error while defining the function

Comment: Ok.  Edit my code as you wish and post it back.